# ESXI TLS configuration

Tags: esxi, tls

I am looking for a way to disable TLS 1.0 on a standalone ESXI 6.0 thats not connected to any vCenter. I see that there are multiple ways to disable it using vCenter and powershell scripts , however i am looking to do this on an esxi without vCenter.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I was searching the same thing as you. Finally, i found the answer by myself.
I did the trick on an ESXi 6.5.0. I hope this will work on yours.

Go to the `/etc/vmware/rhttpproxy` directory and edit the `config.xml` file :

```
vi /etc/vmware/rhttpproxy/config.xml
```

Then, search the `<ssl>` section and change the line

```
<!-- <protocols>tls1.0,tls1.1,tls1.2</protocols> -->
```

to

```
<protocols>tls1.1,tls1.2</protocols>
```

Then, restart the web UI :

```
/etc/init.d/rhttpproxy restart
```